# Dúvida group by oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Quero fazer um group by entre duas tabelas fazendo um inner join.
A tabela de empregado e a tabela empregado no posto. Eu quero que retorne a mais recente entrada em um posto de um dado empregado. Mas só estou conseguindo isso tendo que suprimir duas colunas da query, que é o posto do contrato e a data de entrada no posto:

```
select 
       max(entrada_posto),
       e.id ,   

       --ep.fk_posto_contrato,
       e.admissao,
       e.demissao,
       --ep.entrada_posto,
       ep.saida_posto

  from TB_EMPREGADO e


    inner join TB_EMPREGADO_NO_POSTO ep

     on e.id = ep.fk_empregado

group by

       e.id ,   

       --ep.fk_posto_contrato,
       e.admissao,
       e.demissao,
       --ep.entrada_posto,
       ep.saida_posto
```

Cujo resultado é:

```
"MAX(ENTRADA_POSTO)","ID","ADMISSAO","DEMISSAO","SAIDA_POSTO"
"10/09/2018","1","10/09/2018","",""
"01/10/2020","43","09/13/2019","",""
```

O resultado completo com todas as colunas, dá 2 registros para o id 43, e eu só preciso do último:

```
"MAX(ENTRADA_POSTO)","ID","FK_POSTO_CONTRATO","ADMISSAO","DEMISSAO","ENTRADA_POSTO","SAIDA_POSTO"
"01/10/2020","43","42","09/13/2019","","01/10/2020",""
"10/09/2018","1","21","10/09/2018","","10/09/2018",""
"10/09/2019","43","41","09/13/2019","","10/09/2019",""
```

Há alguma forma de preservar essas colunas e só trazer a data de entrada no posto mais recente, para dado id de empregado?

Answer (score 0):

Faça um `with` ou coloque essa informação numa `sub-query` entre as suas colunas:

Exemplo 1:

```
WITH ultima_entrada AS(
SELECT fk_empregado, 
       MAX(entrada_posto) entrada_posto
  FROM tb_empregado_no_posto
 GROUP BY fk_empregado
)

SELECT MAX(entrada_posto), 
       e.id, 
       e.admissao, 
       e.demissao
  FROM tb_empregado e
 INNER JOIN ultima_entrada ep
    ON e.id = ep.fk_empregado
```

Exemplo 2:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(entrada_posto) entrada_posto
          FROM tb_empregado_no_posto
         WHERE e.id = ep.fk_empregado) entrada_posto, 
       e.id, 
       e.admissao, 
       e.demissao
  FROM tb_empregado e
```

Answer (score 0):

Bruno Warmling,

Obrigado pelas dicas. Tentei as soluções, usando os dois exemplos e não fui muito feliz no primeiro utilizando todas colunas da tabela empregado_no_posto. Pode ser que esqueci algum detalhe.

No exemplo 1 usei assim:

```
WITH ultima_entrada AS(
SELECT fk_empregado, 
       MAX(entrada_posto) entrada_posto
  FROM tb_empregado_no_posto
 GROUP BY fk_empregado

)

SELECT 
       MAX(ep.entrada_posto),
       e.id, 
       e.admissao, 
       e.demissao,
       ep2.entrada_posto,
       ep2.saida_posto,
       ep2.atualizacao,
       ep2.fk_contexto
  FROM tb_empregado e
 INNER JOIN ultima_entrada ep
    ON e.id = ep.fk_empregado
 INNER JOIN tb_empregado_no_posto ep2 ON e.id = ep2.fk_empregado

group by 
e.id,
e.admissao, 
e.demissao,
ep2.entrada_posto,
ep2.saida_posto,
ep2.atualizacao,
ep2.fk_contexto
```

Ainda assim retornou os três registros.

No exemplo 2 retornou corretamente, porém ao acresentar as outras colunas, usando um inner da tabela empregado_no_posto retornou as três linhas:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(entrada_posto) entrada_posto
          FROM tb_empregado_no_posto ep
         WHERE e.id = ep.fk_empregado) entrada_posto , 
       e.id, 
       e.admissao, 
       e.demissao,
       ep2.saida_posto
  FROM tb_empregado e
       inner join tb_empregado_no_posto ep2 on ep2.fk_empregado = e.id
```

Testei outra abordagem, parecido com o exemplo 2 que funcionou. Eu adicionei mais uma comparação no inner join no exemplo 1, acrescentando outro inner. Funcionou, ficou extenso e não muito bonito, aí vai:

> INNER JOIN tb_empregado_no_posto ep2 ON e.id = ep2.fk_empregado and
>   ep2.entrada_posto = ep.entrada_posto

```
WITH ultima_entrada AS(
SELECT fk_empregado, 
       MAX(entrada_posto) entrada_posto
  FROM tb_empregado_no_posto
 GROUP BY fk_empregado

)

SELECT 
       MAX(ep.entrada_posto),
       e.id, 
       e.admissao, 
       e.demissao,
       ep2.entrada_posto,
       ep2.saida_posto,
       ep2.atualizacao,
       ep2.fk_contexto
  FROM tb_empregado e
 INNER JOIN ultima_entrada ep
    ON e.id = ep.fk_empregado
 INNER JOIN tb_empregado_no_posto ep2 ON e.id = ep2.fk_empregado and ep2.entrada_posto = ep.entrada_posto

group by 
e.id,
e.admissao, 
e.demissao,
ep2.entrada_posto,
ep2.saida_posto,
ep2.atualizacao,
ep2.fk_contexto
```

Aqui o resultado final:

```
"MAX(EP.ENTRADA_POSTO)","ID","ADMISSAO","DEMISSAO","ENTRADA_POSTO","SAIDA_POSTO","ATUALIZACAO","FK_CONTEXTO"
"10/09/2018","1","10/09/2018","","10/09/2018","","06-NOV-19 02.47.50.720476 PM","1"
"01/10/2020","43","09/13/2019","","01/10/2020","","10-JAN-20 04.35.40.642123 PM","1"
```

Aqui a solução que traz o mesmo resultado do exemplo 1 adaptado:

```
select ID,FK_POSTO_CONTRATO,FK_EMPREGADO, maior_data.entrada, SAIDA_POSTO,ATUALIZACAO,FK_CONTEXTO FROM tb_empregado_no_posto ep

inner join

(

select ep2.FK_EMPREGADO chave ,max(ep2.ENTRADA_POSTO) entrada FROM tb_empregado_no_posto ep2 group by fk_empregado

) maior_data

on maior_data.chave = ep.fk_empregado and maior_data.entrada = ep.entrada_posto
```

Comment: Se houver uma solução mais efetiva, por favor me digam.